# Stubbing TargetPlatform not working in flutter test

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I have these 2 tests:

```
void main() {
  group('...', () {
    testWidgets('Should ... when the OS is macOS', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          platform: TargetPlatform.macOS,
        ),
      ));
     ...
      assert(Theme.of(context).platform...); // platform is android!!
    });
    testWidgets('Should ... when the OS is windows', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          platform: TargetPlatform.windows,
        ),
      ));
      ...
      assert(Theme.of(context).platform...); // platform is android!!
    });

  });
}
```

I overrided the `platform` in the `theme` of `MaterialApp` explicitly as [per the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/platform.html):

> In a test environment, the platform returned is TargetPlatform.android
> regardless of the host platform. (Android was chosen because the tests
> were originally written assuming Android-like behavior, and we added
> platform adaptations for other platforms later). Tests can check
> behavior for other platforms by setting the platform of the Theme
> explicitly to another TargetPlatform value, or by setting
> debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride.

I also tried setting it via [debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride.html), like this:

```
void main() {
  group('...', () {
    testWidgets('Should ... when the OS is macOS', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // set the OS to macOS
      debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.macOS;

      await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp());
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      BuildContext context = tester.element(find.byType(MaterialApp));
      assert(Theme.of(context).platform...); // Works, platform is macOS

      // reset the default target platform
      debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null;
    });
    testWidgets('Should ... when the OS is windows', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // set the OS to windows
      debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.windows;

      await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp());
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      BuildContext context = tester.element(find.byType(MaterialApp));
      assert(Theme.of(context).platform...); //Platform is still macOS!!

      // reset the default target platform
      debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = null;
    });
  });
}
```

But in the code above the first test only passes but the second fails bcz the `platform` resetting is not working and the platform is still macOS (due to the first test).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may not be a solution to the problem, but moving the windows test to their own file should work. Testing each platform in its own file.